# Outlook.com App - How to create event with HTML body pre-populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ms-office, office365, office365-apps

I'm creating a Mail App for Outlook.com.

I want to create a new event from my read app and pre-populate the body with some html.

I'm using the [Mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161098%28v=office.1501401%29.aspx) method, and it opens a new event successfully.
However, the body content always shows up as plain text, even though I'm sending an HTML string. 
(eg.`"<!Doctype html><html>...</html>"`)

The body parameter is described in the documentation as:

> "The body of the appointment message. The body content is limited to a maximum size of 32 KB."

It doesn't say that it must be a string, or that plaintext is the only thing allowed. Can I create some sort of body object in which I specify the type? How would I do that?

I've tried sending some other (made up) parameters - CoercionType, and/or BodyType, but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body parameter is indeed interpreted as plain text. There currently is no way to coerce it to HTML. I passed this along to the engineering team, hopefully this is something we can improve in the future.